# how to toggle between class list in react using random number function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to convert the js project to react and I need to add a class to a random circle and flash it using calling the same function again but I don't know how to convert this two line of code into react: circles[nextActiveNum].classList.toggle("active");
circles[activeNum].classList.remove("active"); I have made a circle component in react for that and all the state is in a class component.

```
const startButton = document.querySelector("#start");
const endButton = document.querySelector("#end");
const circles = document.querySelectorAll(".circle");


let count = 0;
let activeNum = 0;
let timer;
let pace = 1000;
let rounds = 0;
let gameIsOn = false;

//sounds
const startSound = new Audio("sounds/starter.wav");
const endGameSound = new Audio("sounds/gameover.wav");
const click = new Audio("sounds/click.wav");

console.log(startSound);

// start game functionality starts here

const playAudio = () => {
  startSound.play();
};

const randomNumber = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

const newCircle = (activeNum) => {
  let nextActiveNum = randomNumber(0, 3);
  if (activeNum != nextActiveNum) {
    return nextActiveNum;
  } else {
    return newCircle(activeNum);
  }
};

const startgame = () => {
  gameIsOn = true;
  startButton.style.display = "none";
  endButton.style.display = "initial";
  let nextActiveNum = newCircle(activeNum);
  circles[nextActiveNum].classList.toggle("active");
  circles[activeNum].classList.remove("active");
  activeNum = nextActiveNum;
  timer = setTimeout(startgame, pace);
  pace -= 10;
  rounds++;

  if (rounds >= 2) {
    return endGame();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

Circle component

```
const Circle = ({ active }) => {
  const classList = ['circle'];
  if (active) classList.push('active');
  return <div className={classList.join(' ')}></div>;
};
```

Parent component

```
function randomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

const circles = new Array(4).fill(Circle);

export default function App() {
  const [activeNum, setActiveNum] = useState(null);

  function nextNum() {
    setActiveNum((prev) => {
      let next = prev;
      while (next === prev) next = randomNumber(0, 3);
      return next;
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {circles.map((C, i) => (
        <C active={i === activeNum} />
      ))}
      <br />
      <button onClick={nextNum}>Next</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fwn9xc?file=App.tsx

Let me know if something is unclear.